# How to get Proper Resolution for VR Headset?

Tags: javascript, three.js, virtual-reality, webvr, htc-vive

I'm creating a WebVR application using three.js. Currently I'm trying to set the resolution of the window to the resolution of the hmd in order to get a clearer picture. I've been trying to get this information using [VREyeParameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VREyeParameters) renderWidth/Height components. However with the Vive I'm using I keep getting a resolution much larger than the supposed 2160x1200 (I got the width to be 3448). Am I grabbing the wrong information and is there somewhere else I need to be getting these values from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values look correct.

You are rendering to a temporary texture that is projected with barrel distortion to the destination LCD. For best quality, the temporary texture is in higher resolution.

Comment: The project I'm developing uses a raymarched system, is there any way for me to get the distortion function from the HMD? Or is this something I should just leave as is and render as if there is no distortion?

Comment: You probably shouldn't touch that.   
But if you really want to, you would have go around WebVR's frame presentation and display your own fullscreen canvas with projections applied - this might work only on platforms without a dedicated VR screen (so no desktop HMDs - only mobile). Possibly will work on Cardboard/Daydream.  
Not sure about GearVR not Oculus Go - AFAIK they only work in WebVR in their dedicated applications - and you have no option for a fullscreen canvas there. You still need to do your own per-headset projection and color distortion.

Comment: Thanks for the great response, since I'm aiming for desktop HMDs I will just leave it alone for now.